# ¿Select dependiente en Django?

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, ajax

Cómo hago para colocar cuatro select a mi template que muestren estado, municipio, Localidad? y por supuesto, si el usuario selecciona el estado DF, el otro select traiga solamente los municipios y localidades. Cómo lo hago?

[image: BD Estados y Municipios de Mexico]

Con el fin de que ya cargados dentro de combox los guarde, a una tabla de usuarios que se registren y seleccionen su estado, municipio y localidad, gracias.

Comment: Hola, lo mejor es que muestres los modelos, formularios, templates de Django que estás usando.

Answer (score 7):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear el formulario con tus tres tablas, luego usando AJAX y jQuery consultar dinámicamente los modelos de acuerdo a la opción que el usuario ha seleccionado.

Primero, el formulario. Observa que en el `queryset` de cada `ModelChoiceField` estoy usando un `all()`, esto es necesario para que se pueda escoger una opción válida al momento de usar AJAX para filtrar los resultados.

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

from .models import Estado, Municipio, Localidad


class UbicacionForm(forms.Form):
    estado = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=u'Estado', 
        queryset=Estado.objects.all()
    )
    municipio = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=u'Municipio', 
        queryset=Municipio.objects.all()
    )
    localidad = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=u'Localidad', 
        queryset=Localidad.objects.all()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UbicacionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['municipio'].queryset = Municipio.objects.none()
        self.fields['localidad'].queryset = Localidad.objects.none()
```

En la vista, tendrías algo como esto.

**views.py:**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from djabgo.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import UbicacionForm
from .models import Municipio, Localidad 

def vista_ubicacion(request):
    form = UbicacionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UbicacionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Guardar los datos
            url = reverse('home')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Creamos las funciones que recibirán los filtros vía AJAX, estas funciones son las que deberán ser llamadas desde tu template.

**ajax.py:**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Localidad, Municipio


def get_municipios(request):
    estado_id = request.GET.get('estado_id')
    municipios = Municipio.objects.none()
    options = '<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>'
    if estado_id:
        municipios = Municipio.objects.filter(estado_id=estado_id)   
    for municipio in municipios:
        options += '<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (
            municipio.pk,
            municipio.municipio
        )
    response = {}
    response['municipios'] = options
    return JsonResponse(response)


def get_localidades(request):
    municipio_id = request.GET.get('municipio_id')
    localidades = Localidad.objects.none()
    options = '<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>'
    if municipio_id:
        localidades = Localidad.objects.filter(municipio_id=municipio_id)   
    for localidad in localidades:
        options += '<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (
            localidad.pk,
            localidad.localidad
        )
    response = {}
    response['localidades'] = options
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Ya que hemos agregado funciones nuevas, necesitamos crear la ruta hacia esas funciones AJAX actualizando las URLs.

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .ajax import get_municipios, get_localidades

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ajax/get_municipios/$', get_municipios, name='get_municipios'),
    url(r'^ajax/get_localidades/$', get_localidades, name='get_localidades'),
    # ...
]
```

Ahora, necesitamos que cuando se seleccione un estado, se filtren los municipios, y que cuando se seleccione un municipio, se filtren las localidades. Esto lo tenemos que definir en el template (o en un archivo JavaScript importado en tu template) mediante un `<script></script>`.

**template.html:**

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            {{ form.estado.label_tag }} 
            {{ form.estado }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.municipio.label_tag }} 
            {{ form.municipio }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.localidad.label_tag }} 
            {{ form.localidad }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#id_estado").on("change", getMunicipios);
            $("#id_estado").on("change", getLocalidades);
        });

        function getMunicipios() {
            var estadoId = $("#id_estado").val();
            if (estadoId) {
                // Eliminamos las opciones anteriores del select
                $("#id_municipio").html("");
                var request = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "{% url 'get_municipios' %}",
                    data: {
                        "estado_id": estadoId,
                    },
                });
                request.done(function(response) {
                    // Agregamos los resultados al select
                    $("#id_proceso").html(response.municipios);
                    $("#id_localidad").html("<option value='' selected='selected'>---------</option>");
                    $("#id_municipio, #id_localidad").trigger("change");
                });
            } else {
                $("#id_municipio").html("<option value='' selected='selected'>---------</option>");
                $("#id_localidad").html("<option value='' selected='selected'>---------</option>");
                $("#id_municipio, #id_localidad").trigger("change");
            }
        }    

        function getLocalidades() {
            var municipioId = $("#id_municipio").val();
            if (municipioId) {
                // Eliminamos las opciones anteriores del select
                $("#id_localidad").html("");
                var request = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "{% url 'get_localidades' %}",
                    data: {
                        "municipio_id": municipioId,
                    },
                });
                request.done(function(response) {
                    // Agregamos los resultados al select
                    $("#id_localidad").html(response.localidades);
                    $("#id_localidad").trigger("change");
                });
            } else {
                $("#id_localidad").html("<option value='' selected='selected'>---------</option>");
                $("#id_localidad").trigger("change");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

No te compliques la vida, este paquete te va a ayudar
- https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Tus modelos solo necesitan un ajuste muy ligero para encadenarlos, el paquete se explica por si mismo.

Answer (score 0):

la pregunta es de hace 3 años, pero supongo que alguien más se lo preguntará y si les sirve comparto como lo he resuelto, prácticamente solo usando JS, HTML y el contexto con el que se renderiza

```
<div class="col-3">
  {{form.estado|add_class:"form-select"}}
</div>
```

En la view creo la variable municipios

```
def view_del_template_renderizado(request)
    municipios = Municipios.objects.all()
    
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'municipios':municipios
        }
```

Creo un seleccionable "falso" con la variable municipios en el template

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="selector input-group mb-3">
     <label for="form.municipos" class="col-auto col-form-label my-1"> 
      <strong>Municipos: </strong>
     </label>
     <select class="form-select form-select-sm" style="font-size:1rem"id="municipios">
     <option id="default_sel">--------</option>
        {% for municipio in municipios  %}
         <option class="js" estado="{{municipio.estado.id}}">
         {{municipio.municipio}}
         </option>
        {% endfor %}
   </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row my-2">
    <div class="col-3 d-none">
     {{form.municipios|add_class:"form-select"}}
    </div>
</div>
```

En realidad el truco se concentra en el atributo estado de la etiqueta option del seleccionable falso y en definir la clase "js" para todos los elementos option

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("id_estado").addEventListener("change", function(element){
    var select = document.getElementById('id_estado');
    var current_option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    opciones = document.getElementsByClassName("js")
    for (var i=0; i < opciones.length; i++){

        if (opciones[i].getAttribute('estado') != current_option){
             opciones[i].setAttribute('class','js d-none')
        } else {
            opciones[i].setAttribute('class','js')
        }
    }
    });
```

Así este bloque de JS lo único que hace es que cuando cambia la opción del estado itera sobre todos los elementos de la localidad y si el estado es diferente al valor de la opción actual lo desaparece y si no sigue dejándolo visible

```
 document.getElementById("municipio").addEventListener("change", function(element){
        var select = document.getElementById('municipio');
        var current_option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        var other_selector = document.getElementById('id_municipio');
        other_selector.selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex
    });
   </script>
```

En el segundo bloque se detecta si el municipio cambia (ya con los municipios filtrados en el seleccionable "falso") entonces el valor de indice se le asigna al seleccionable "real".
Una tercera dependiencia significaría repetir los pasos, es decir crear un seleccionable "falso" (gracias a una variable localidades desde el view) con las localidades con un atributo "municipio" igual a la de "estado" para saber a cual pertenecen. Espero que mi explicación no sea demasiado confusa.