# Como mostrar contenido en un select que dependa de otro select?

Tags: python, django

Mi duda es la siguiente... tengo un select que es llave foranea, y a la vez este tiene otra llave foranea, y lo que quiero hacer es seleccionar un dato del primer select y que el segundo select cambie su contenido dependiendo del primer select

Mi codigo

**`Models.py`** de correspondencia, son mas datos pero no los pongo

```
 class corresp(models.Model):
     Secretaria=models.ForeignKey(secretarias, null=True, blank=False)
     Unidad=models.ForeignKey(unidad, null=True, blank=False)
```

**`Models.py`** de Usuario

```
class secretarias(models.Model):
    nombre_secretaria=models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ubicacion=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre_secretaria)

class unidad(models.Model):
    nombre_unidad = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Secretaria= models.ForeignKey(secretarias, null=True, blank=True)
```

Código del archivo **`views.py`**

```
 def corresp_crear(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CorrespondenciaForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                 c = form.save(commit=False)
                 c.user = request.user
                 c.save()
                 messages.success(request, 'Correspondencia creada correctamente .')
              return redirect('correspondencia:corresp_listar')
      else:
            form = CorrespondenciaForm()
      return render(request, 'registrarCorrespondencia/formulario1.html', {'form': form})
```

Parte del Codigo del archivo **`formulario1.html`**

```
   <div class="well" style="overflow: auto">
     <label>Destino por Areas</label><br>
       <div class="col-md-6">{{ form.Secretaria.label}} {{ form.Secretaria}}</div>
       <div class="col-md-6">  {{ form.Unidad.label}} {{ form.Unidad}}</div>          
   </div>
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2040/select-dependiente-en-django

Comment: https://axiacore.com/blog/django-y-selects-encadenados/

Answer (score 2):

Como aparece en los enlaces que te pone Tengito123, una de las opciones más "puras" sería tirar de jQuery para hacer el encadenamiento de los selects a mano.

Yo generalmente prefiero usar para los selects [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) que ya tiene una funcionalidad para encadenar los selects de forma muy sencilla y que además te da la funcionalidad de autocompletar.

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo de algunas de las piezas código importantes, para que veas cómo quedaría:

```
# forms.py

from dal import autocomplete

class CorrespondenciaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Correspondencia
        fields = ['unidad', 'secretaria', ]
        widgets = {
            'unidad': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='unidad-autocomplete')
            'secretaria': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='secretaria-autocomplete', 
                                                    forward=['unidad', ])
        }
        ... 



# views.py

class SecretariaAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = models.Secretaria.objects.all()
        unidad = self.forwarded.get('unidad', None)
        if self.unidad:
            qs = qs.filter(unidad=unidad)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(nombre_secretaria__icontains=self.q)

        return results
```

Creo que esta es una forma muy limpita y muy fácil de conseguir lo que estás consultando.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, me parecio interesante lo que me dijiste y una manera corta de como obtener lo que quiero, pero me da una duda... como estoy traabjando solo con def y , no con clases en mis views me pregunto si esa parte que pusiste para class SecretariaAutocomplete esta destino solo para el uso en clases? o es valido para def ???

Comment: Bueno, lo puse con clases porque yo suelo trabajar con clases y es lo más actual, pero puedes hacerlo sin clases sin problema. Lo único que tendrías que hacer es una vista que te devuelva el listado de resultados filtrados.

Comment: oooh gracias muchas gracias , e estado tratando de hacer con la libreria que me indicaste pero tuve un problema debido a la importación del "select2", revise la documentación de la librería pero aun no me da bien me sale un error al ponerla en los settings , estoy trabajando con la version 1.11 de django, sera que eso afecta al uso de la libreria???

Comment: No, yo uso Django 1.11 también y no me da problemas. Sé que no es compatible con jQuery 3.x, quizás por ahí puedas solucionar algo.