# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un select dinamico con jQuery en django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en django, y tengo dos select, uno que muestra las regiones, y otro que muestra todas las comunas, y necesito que dependiendo de la selección de la región, se muestran las comunas en el otro select, y debo hacerlo con jquery.

mi modelo de base de datos lo tengo de la siguiente manera con región y comuna:

```
class Region(models.Model):
nro_region = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Comuna(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)
region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

y todos los datos de las regiones y comunas los inserte con el django admin, y estoy mostrando los selects en mi template de la siguiente manera, donde hago un ciclo for para recorrerlos y mostrarlos:

```
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="cboregion">Región:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="cboregion" id="cboregion" onchange="console.log(this.value)" required >
                <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                {% for r in regiones %}
                <option value="{{ r.id }}">{{ r.id }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="cbocomuna">Comuna:</label>
            <select name="cbocomuna" id="cbocomuna" class="form-control" onchange="console.log(this.value)" disabled required>
                <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                {% for c in comunas %}
                <option value="{{ c.id }}">{{ c.region.id }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hasta ahora solo he podido conseguir que se active el select de comuna, si previamente se selecciono alguna opción del select de región, pero no sé como puedo hacer para que se muestren las comunas que tengan el id de la región:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cboregion").change(function(){
     if($("#cboregion").val() != ""){   //si una region es seleccionada quitara la propiedad disabled
        $("#cbocomuna").prop('disabled', false);
     }
     else{
       $("#cbocomuna").prop('disabled', true);  //si una comuna no esta seleccionada mantendra la propiedad disabled
     }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Tal vez mi otra respuesta te pueda ayudar: [¿Select dependiente en Django?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2040/select-dependiente-en-django/2057#2057)

Comment: voy a probar aver que tal funciona, lo malo esque siempre te enseñan de una forma distinta a todas las formas que encuentras en internet jajaja, muchas gracias amigo y felices fiestas

Comment: saludos,, solucionaste le problema quiza !!

Comment: Pude solucionarlo ayer, pero no de la manera en que quizás fuese la mejor, pues solo fui agregando las regiones y comunas en un json y luego fui recorriendo el arreglo con jquery para llenar los select dependiendo de la selección de la región.

Comment: una cosa que olvide comentar, es que en el json le agregue exactamente la misma id de las comunas y regiones que están en la bd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un atributo a las opciones de las comunas que contenga la región a la que corresponde.

Tu código HTML quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="cboregion">Región:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="cboregion" id="cboregion" required >
            <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
            {% for r in regiones %}
                <option value="{{ r.id }}">{{ r.nombre }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="cbocomuna">Comuna:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="cbocomuna" id="cbocomuna" disabled required>
            <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
            {% for c in comunas %}
                <option value="{{ c.id }}" data-region="{{ c.region.id }}">{{ c.nombre }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

A continuación, puedes ver un ejemplo del filtrado de comunas según la selección de la región.

```js
const $region = $('#cboregion');
const $comuna = $('#cbocomuna');
    
$region.change(function() {
    $comuna.val('');
    
    $comuna.prop('disabled', !Boolean($region.val()));
    $comuna.find('option[data-region]').hide();
    $comuna.find('option[data-region="' + $region.val() + '"]').show();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="cboregion">Región:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cboregion" id="cboregion" required >
              <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
              <option value="1">Primera región</option>
              <option value="2">Segunda región</option>
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="cbocomuna">Comuna:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="cbocomuna" id="cbocomuna" disabled required>
              <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
              <option value="1" data-region="1">Primera comuna</option>
              <option value="2" data-region="1">Segunda comuna</option>
              <option value="3" data-region="2">Tercera comuna</option>
              <option value="4" data-region="2">Cuarta comuna</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me ha sido muy útil y pude resolver el problema!!